# How to get Substring in Hadoop Hive?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

My question is how to get a substring in Hive by an indication in the string. My Column values format is like this:

```
/Country/State/City/Suburb/Street
```

here I only need to get Country.

I have fond that SPLIT which returns an array of string delimited by '/'.
And also SUBSTR(string a, int begin) which returns a substring from indicated begin.

In split I need to again access an array in which the first element is the desired one, but just want to know if there is any other easier way to get the Countries.

thanks

Comment: `split()` is about as easy as it gets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with regular expression to extract `Country`. Using regular expression hive query is:

```
select regexp_extract(column,'\/(.*)/.*/.*/.*/',1) from substring_tbl;
```

**My create table statement:**

```
create external table substring_tbl(
column string)
LOCATION '/user/root/hive_substring/';
```

**Your Input Data:**

```
/Country/State/City/Suburb/Street
```

Query and regular expression to extract desired data:

```
select regexp_extract(column,'\/(.*)/.*/.*/.*/',1) from substring_tbl;
```

**Output:**

```
Country
```

Info: `regexp_extract()` returns the string extracted using the pattern. More detail about `regexp_extract()` is available on hive [LanguageManual+UDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

But in case,if you change your input data into different form then you must change your regular expression too.

**UPDATE1**

Query using `split()` function to extract desired data.

```
select split(column, '\\/')[1] from substring_tbl;
```

Comment: complete overkill.  all you need is `split(column, '\\/')[1]`

Comment: Yes, this a nice way to do. Thanks a lot for the answer. I have updated the answer.